# How can I create a PHP-like associative array from a webservice in VB.NET

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, arrays

How can I create the following array of associative arrays in Visual Basic (ASP)?

```
  array(
       array('customer' => 'khl',  'city' => 'bune'),
       array('customer' => 'Kla',  'value' =>    'Swa')
   )
```

Comment: .NET is not really a language, so what language are you referring to?

Comment: I mean .net platform languages, like c# , vb

Comment: Yes, which one specifically are you using?

Comment: I have code conversion tools, so i can convert vb to c# or c# to vb.

Comment: Ugh. But which one is your application *mainly* written in?

Comment: my application is written in vb.net

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var array = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();

array.Add(new Dictionary<string,string>());
array[0].Add("customer", "khl");
array[0].Add("city", "bune");

array.Add(new Dictionary<string,string>());
array[1].Add("customer", "Kla");
array[1].Add("city", "Swa");
```

You can make this simpler by having your details as a struct, if you know the parameters are in a set form:

```
struct Customer
{
    public string Name;
    public string City;
}

var array = new List<Customer>();
array.Add(new Customer { Name = "khl", City = "bune" });
array.Add(new Customer { Name = "Kla", City = "Swa" });
```

Here's the documentation for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz.aspx)
And here's the documentation for `List<T>`: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: I can not set it in soap header, i am using php webservice, there is nested array in arguments.

Comment: You didn't specify ASP.NET (or what language you were using) so I just went with what you gave me. If you're trying to parse it out from a serialized form, you'll need to write a parser.

Comment: yes, actually i am using vb.net, i have php webservice which need nested array as arguments. so the above code is ok. but when i send over to php service its return internal error.

Comment: In future please be specific in your questions, supplying all the necessary information. It's better to give too much information than to give too little.

Comment: ok sure, can you provide the information how can i send over httpwebrequest.